# Android Maps, drawing in Overlay constructor

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, draw

I have a `path()` which is created from a json object. I pass the JSON object to my overlay object in my constructor.

Objects that extend `Overlay` always call `draw()` any time the map is moved, rendered, touched, anything. Even if your overlay isn't visible or nearby or anything.

I want to generate my path object in a for loop, actually a nested loop as the json object contains nested json arrays. This has a high theoretical computation time, so I don't want to do it in the `draw()` method. Instead I tried to do the logic in my constructor, to make the `path()` file, and then call that path file only once in the `draw()` method  where required here `canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);`

Unfortunately, when I create my path in the constructor, it does not pan with the map. But when I create it, the exact same code, in the `draw()` method, it does have the desired functionality: a path that fences a portion of the map.

The problem is that the `draw()` method will then call my double for loop over and over again, and the performance hit is obvious and debilitating. Even putting the loop in `new Thread()` within draw() does not help performance. Running it in the constructor would be ideal, but then the path does not pan with the map.

similarly putting a private boolean flip within the `draw()` method, to make the desired code only run, does not work either. the path will not appear on the map unless it is being constantly redrawn, which is too arduous of a task.

The problem with other answers on this site regarding this issue is that people are making squares, circles and images, which only require one call within `draw()`, not a loop to generate the path.

suggestions? something about the `draw()` method helps overlays stick to the map, how can I run my for loop only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few considerations for you:

1. you should not be overriding the draw() method. The Overlay class already takes care of the whole panning operation for you. Read the docs that you'll find it.
2. the new API is a few thousand times easier to use. With a simple code such as:

   ```
   PolylineOptions p = new new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(0xFFEE8888);
   for( //... first for .... ){
      for( // .... how many you'll need to nest... ){
         // compute your JSON and get lat/long pair
         p.add(new LatLng(lat, lon));
       }
    }
    getMap().addPolyline(p);
   ```

and let the map class deal with the panning and zooming.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the new api, is it backwards compatible with gingerbread?

Comment: do you have a solution for the current api? I am not using fragments, don't want to alienate open gl 1.1 users and would prefer not to switch the way I am managing API keys because my compile script would also have to be changed

Comment: I am using a class which extends Overlay. this doesn't help me.... can you elaborate? My custom class tries to create the path object within the constructor but it only works when I put it in the draw class, which I know I don't want to do, but I don't have the solution

Comment: thanks for the info so far though, btw. the new map is definitely an option

Comment: Hi, I wrote that 1st answer a bit on the rush and now I'm having an extra read for you. Apparently I was wrong, if you want a path on the V1 of the maps you have to extend Overlay, override draw() and draw it yourself. Considering your route is computational intensive the way to do it would be to cache each overlay area on a Bitmap (probably using a LruCache) and whenever possible re-use the same bitmap instead of re-calculating it. As you can see, it's a lot of work, and it might be a very good idea to just use the V2 of the maps. Happy coding!

Comment: yes, thank you, I did begin to implement maps v2 and have to rewrite a lot of code. This may be a useful exercise as I didn't realize they are fazing out v1 maps all of a sudden

Comment: would like to correct this: the polyline needs to be within the first for loop and needs to be added to the map after the inner for loop completes. Otherwise extra lines get drawn between separated polygons

Answer (score 0):

Although you have already accept an answer, here goes the approach I use for this. In the example code bellow, I´m using the old `MapView`, but the concept should work in any version. I'm also using it with `mapforges` (with minimum adjustments).

**Concept**

- Build you `path` on first `draw()` call, and record position of point(0)
- on next `draw()` if point(0) position changed, map has moved. Offset ´path` by same value before draw it.
- If zoom changed, recreate the `path`object.

**Performance**

With a 10.000 points path in a medium range device it takes about `2 ms` per cached `draw()` call. When path needs to be rebuild (when zoom changed) it takes about `80 ms`.

Of cource you can also cache the different path zoom levels, trading a litle more performance by some more memory.

**Example Code**

The draw()method only checks if there is a zoom change (if so ask the path to be rebuild) and if map has moved (if so offset path) and finally draws the path.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);
    if(shadow) return;
    if(mp.getPoints() == null || mp.getPoints().size() < 2) return;

    Projection projection = mapview.getProjection();
    int lonSpanNew = projection.fromPixels(0,mapview.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6() - 
            projection.fromPixels(mapview.getWidth(),mapview.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6();
    if(lonSpanNew != pathInitialLonSpan)
        pathBuild();
    else{ //check if path need to be offset
        projection.toPixels(mp.getPoints().get(0), p1);
        if(p1.x != pathInitialPoint.x || p1.y != pathInitialPoint.y){
            path.offset(p1.x - pathInitialPoint.x, p1.y - pathInitialPoint.y);
            pathInitialPoint.x = p1.x;
            pathInitialPoint.y = p1.y;
        }

    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint); 
}
```

The path has to be built every time zoom changes. The zoom change detection is done using pathInitialLonSpan as getZoomLevel() is not shyncronous with map zoom animation.

```
private void pathBuild(){
    path.rewind(); 
    if(mp.getPoints() == null || mp.getPoints().size() < 2) return;

    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    pathInitialLonSpan = projection.fromPixels(0,mapView.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6() - 
            projection.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth(),mapView.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6();

    projection.toPixels(mp.getPoints().get(0), pathInitialPoint);
    path.moveTo(pathInitialPoint.x,pathInitialPoint.y); 

    for(int i=1; i<mp.getPoints().size(); i++){
        projection.toPixels(mp.getPoints().get(i), p1);
        int distance2 = (pPrev.x - p1.x) * (pPrev.x - p1.x) + (pPrev.y - p1.y) * (pPrev.y - p1.y); 
        if(distance2 > 9){
            path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
            pPrev.set(p1.x, p1.y);
        }
    }
```

Regards.